# rails create my_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

any one can give me a idea why when I try create my_app
which is not working, and only showing:

```
usage:
    rails new APP_PATH [options]
options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]
  -b, [builder=TEMPLATE]...
```

and under my site folder, I couldn't find the my_app folder.
when I open the text mate by typing mate my_app, how can I make it show the folder location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have setup TextMate as command line tool, simply do

```
$ rails new my_app
$ mate my_app
```

and it will open the newly generated app in TextMate

Comment: thanks for that, all go now. my next question is: I try to follow the tutorial, and type script/server but can't start server yet, I think because I didn't install any server yet, the video suggest webrick. could anyone give me a good one for now. and any instruction how to install please

Comment: In Rails 3, just type `rails server`, or `rails s` which is the same thing

Comment: @Wayneinnz, apparently you are working with Rails 3 and the tutorial is Rails 2. You'd better find a Rails 3 tutorial or you will run into more problems.

Answer (score 0):

The proper command is `rails new app_name`